# Copy Document center to record center for EDRMS

Tags: sharepoint-online, records-center

I'm building an EDRMS for a client on SharePoint Online.  I've created the document center with subsites and folders according to clients' file hierarchy.
For clients' purpose we decided to have a separate Record center.  But the Record Center will have the exact same structure than the document center.
Is it a good idea (to save time) to copy the Document Center structure to the Record Center before uploading any files?  If so, how do I do it - with scripts or do I save the document center subsites as templates and create them in the record center?
Any ideas/input to save time instead of redoing everything would be welcome?